# Informix JDBC driver connection: table has been dropped, altered or renamed

Tags: jdbc, informix

There is a problem when I get a connection from the Informix JDBC driver. The problem is "Table (table_name) has been dropped, altered or renamed".
But this problem does not always appear. For example, I have four tasks to deal with; every task needs to get connection from the Informix JDBC driver, and two tasks are successful but two tasks fail.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhuaZ.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't post questions that depend on images.  Include the text from the image in the question directly.  You seem to be using Pentaho.  Does the snapshot version information apply to Pentaho or the Informix JDBC driver or something else?  Should you tag the question with [tag:pentaho]?  Which version of the Informix JDBC driver are you using?  What platform are you running on?  What sequence of operations is the code doing on the database?